# Retrieve a string from text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some text files which contains execution on windows scheduler jobs, I am trying to read a specific value from these files and send email,

For example: `File_1.txt` has below lines and if the rejected count is greater than `0000000000` then we should get notified.

```
RECORDS READ:        0000000042
RECORDS SKIPPED:     0000000000
RECORDS PROCESSED:   0000000042
RECORDS REJECTED:    0000000001
```

I have tried using `Get-Content` and `Select-string` cmdlets to get the string "`Records Rejected: 0000000001`" but not sure how to proceed after this.

```
$Output = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\Logs\*.log" |Select -Index 22
$output

$output = Select-String  -Path 'C:\Powershell\Logs\*.log'  -Pattern 'REJECTED:'
```

Comment: is that the entire file?

Comment: There are more data to it, this is the data i am interested in.

Comment: ah! i thot that your use of `-Index` was significant. since it is not a needed part of the selection process, i will ignore it. there are faster & better ways to get the 21st item from an array ... [*grin*]

Comment: The select -index should work with one file if that's the right line.  The first line is line 0.  Select-string returns a matchinfo object.  You might want something like `$output = (Select-String  -Path 'C:\Powershell\Logs\*.log'  -Pattern 'REJECTED:').line` that singles out the line property with the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

This makes a lot of assumptions about the content of your files, so it if doesn't work you might need to update your question with more details:

```bsh
$filename = "c:\src\scratch\text\log.txt";

# read an array containing each line of text from the file
# (there's a performance issue if the file has very many lines)
$lines = Get-Content -Path $filename;

# split each line into an array of words
# (another performance issue if the file is very large)
$records = $lines | % { @(, $_.Split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)) };

# find the line where the second word is "REJECTED:"
# (assumes there's only ever exactly one "REJECTED" line)
# (arrays are zero-based so the first index is [0], and the second index is [1])
$rejected = $records | where-object { $_[1] -eq "REJECTED:" };

# convert the third word from that line into a number
$count = [int] $rejected[2];

write-host "rejected count = $count";
```

You could compress it all into a single pipeline if you're feeling brave, but I've left it expanded so it's easier to see what's going on.

When I run it with your example file I get this output:

```
rejected count = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the prettiest code... in fact it's not even code I'm happy with... but it works and the intention is that it works in a way that's understandable to you!

Give it a whirl and see how you get on `:-)`

```
$file = "C:\temp\file.txt"

$content = Get-Content file

$rawRecordsRejected = $content | Where-Object {$_ -like "RECORDS REJECTED:*" }

Write-Host $rawRecordsRejected -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

$title = ($rawRecordsRejected -split ":")[0].Trim()
$recordsRejected = ($rawRecordsRejected -split ":")[1].Trim()

Write-Host $title -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $recordsRejected -ForegroundColor Green
```

Answer (score 0):

this gets the rejected count by using the way that PoSh handles `-match` when the object on the left is a collection. you get the item, not a boolean.

```
# fake reading in a text file as raw text
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
RECORDS READ:        0000000042
RECORDS SKIPPED:     0000000000
RECORDS PROCESSED:   0000000042
RECORDS REJECTED:    0000000001
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$TargetLine = 'rejected'
$MaxRejectsAllowed = 0

$RejectedCount = [int]($InStuff -match $TargetLine).Split(':')[-1].Trim()
if ($RejectedCount -gt $MaxRejectsAllowed)
    {
    Write-Warning ('The Rejected_Records count [ {0} ] is above the threshold of [ {1} ].' -f $RejectedCount, $MaxRejectsAllowed)
    }
```

output ...

```
WARNING: The Rejected_Records count [ 1 ] is above the threshold of [ 0 ].
```